# Centos 7 Crontab not running with adjtime error

Tags: centos, cron

Wonder if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have a newly built centos 7 server running as a webserver. I have set up a cronjob in crontab but upon running the crontab I get the following error:

```
./crontab: line 16: adjtime: command not found
```

Line 16 in crontab is:

```
* * * * * root /var/www/html/protected/yiic cron
```

Does anyone have any idea what `adjtime` is. I am thinking that it relates to `hwclock` but Im not sure.

If I run `/var/www/html/protected/yiic cron` at cli it runs fine.

Any Ideas

Thanks 
Richard

Comment: I'm assuming you have read the [adjtime man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/3/adjtime/)?

Comment: What does your script do, perhaps posting it's contents may help. It sounds like it is attempting to call `adjtime`. If so, you may want to ensure that your script is setting the environment properly as this can really mess up cron tasks.